# Tooltip set by Style is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The tooltip for the below listbox is set using a setter.  Nothing appears for a tooltip on mouse over.

I suspect the issue is the itemssource of the listbox itself.  The listbox is bound to a list of AttributeItems called CandidateAttributes.  An element of that list is an observablecollection called AttributePath, and the property in the Attribute path I am trying to bind the tooltip to is called ConceptualPath.  Below is the definition for CandidateAttributes-

```
 public static List<AttributeItem> CoBRRaAttributes { get; set; }
```

The AttributeItems class-

```
public class AttributeItem 
{
    private string _displayName = "";
            private ObservableCollection<CoBRRa_WPF.CoBRRaUtilities.ViewModels.QueryTool.AttributeCollection> _AttributePath;


    public AttributeItem(int id, string displayName, ObservableCollection<CoBRRa_WPF.CoBRRaUtilities.ViewModels.QueryTool.AttributeCollection> attributePath)
    {
        DisplayName = displayName;
        AttributePath = attributePath;

    }

    public ObservableCollection<CoBRRa_WPF.CoBRRaUtilities.ViewModels.QueryTool.AttributeCollection> AttributePath
    {
        get
        {
            return _AttributePath;
        }
        set
        {
            _AttributePath = value;
        }
    }
  }
```

The xmal-

```
            <ListBox 
            Name="lstCandidates" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UIProperties.CandidateAttributes}"
            >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip" Value="{Binding AttributePath.ConceptualPath}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

I can substitute some text in the place of Binding AttributePath.ConceptualPath and the tooltip displays that text.  Just can't figure out why it does not work in the binding.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: AttributePath is a collection. Which item in the this collection do you want to bind against? There may be several.

Comment: ConceptualPath is what i want to bind to.  Thought that the line "Binding AttributePath.ConceptualPath" would populate the tooltip since ConceptualPath is a property of the AttributePath collection.  I neglected to include snippet from CoBRRa_WPF.CoBRRaUtilities.ViewModels.QueryTool.AttributeCollection.  Will update.

Comment: No, attributePath returns an ObservableCollection and this one has no ConceptualPath property. AttributePath is a *collection* of AttributeCollections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to `AttributePath.ConceptualPath` but `AttributePath` returns an `ObservableCollection<AttributeCollection>` and this one has no `ConceptualPath` property.

You should either change the type of the `AttributePath` property to just `CoBRRa_WPF.CoBRRaUtilities.ViewModels.QueryTool.AttributeCollection` or bind to a specific `AttributeCollection`, for example the first one:

```
<Setter Property="Control.ToolTip" Value="{Binding AttributePath[0].ConceptualPath}"/>
```

Also make sure that `ConceptualPath` is a public property of the `AttributeCollection` class.

**Edit:**

If you want to the display a list of paths in the tooltip, you should use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AttributePath}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConceptualPath}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: That makes sense.  Tried AttributePath[0].ConceptualPath but did not work.

Comment: I verified that ConceptualPath is a public property of the AttributeCollection class.

Comment: So is the AttributePath collection populated? Did you debug to find out?

Comment: It is populated.  In fact, I did get this to partially work by putting this in a style, then specifying the ItemsSource of ItemsControl as AttributePath.  That approach had issues of its own, but did populate the tooltip.

Comment: What does UIProperties.CandidateAttributes return? Please provide a MCVE of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AttributePath}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Name="xTooltip" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ConceptualPath}">

Comment: The above worked, but could not get rid of empty tooltips on the UI

Comment: The UIProperties.CandidateAttributes is a property that returns CobbraAttributes in a getter

Comment: Wait!  Using AttributePath[0].ConceptualPath DID give me the first item in the list.  It does not show the whole list, only the first element.  How can I change this to bind to the list and not just the first element of that list

Comment: Yes, of course it only shows the first element. If you want to display the ConceptualPath of all items in the collection, you should use an ItemsControl.

Comment: You are on my Christmas list!!  That worked.  Thanks so much!